# ASP.NET MVC dynamic links from Ajax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I trying to do something like this in my MVC project.

```
 $(selector).append(`<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" asp-controller="${controller}" asp-action="${method}" asp-route-domain="${item}">${item}</a>`)
```

Where `$(selector)` is bootstrap list (`<ul>`). However after successful Ajax call I have all data to populate the list, the problem come with links where after render looks like in the DOM

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
   asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-domain="something">Something</a>
```

and if a click on nothing happens.I saw other links in my project that after render have `href="Home/Index"`. I want to populate my list dynamically from Ajax but links does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `asp-controller`, `asp-action` and `asp-route-domain` are just [Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> Tag Helpers enable server-side code to participate in creating and rendering HTML elements in Razor files

This means the Tag Helper you use in Razor files will be generated to proper HTML code when the client-side receives the code from server-side.
When you write your `jQuery` code, you're working with the client-side, so you have to use the equivalent HTML code instead.

Those you are using are [Anchor Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

The code in your Razor file

```
`<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" asp-controller="${controller}" asp-action="${method}" asp-route-domain="${item}">${item}</a>`
```

Would generate the equivalent HTML code:

```
`<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="${controller}/${method}?domain=${item}">${item}</a>`
```